# Set up domain for my website

Tags: dns

So I am hosting a Drupal installation on a Ubuntu Server. This server has a fixed IP. I've bought a domain for it, but I don't quite get how to set it up.

I got to put it into a DNS server, but which one? I don't need DynDNS, since as mentioned the IP is fixed.

Comment: That depends heavily on the domain provider.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the static IP address into the A record. If you're using email at the same location, enter it for the MX record as well.

The DNS server will be on the same site as the place you registered the domain (ask the domain registrar).

Are you hosting on a different company than that with whom you registered the domain?